# How to efficiently generate strong ETags using a System.Net.Cryptography HashAlgorithm?

Tags: c#, hash, asp.net-web-api, cryptography, asp.net-web-api2

When handling HttpRequestMessages in WebAPI2, we're looking at multiple ways to handle If-None-Match using strong ETags.

Hashing the response content to a strong ETag is the most obvious solution but needs the hashing process to scale.

It appears that the best practice code for generating a hash is something like:

```
using (var hasher = SHA1.Create())
    return hasher.ComputeHash(stream);
```

What costs are associated with creating a HashAlgorithm object?

Is using a byte array any more efficient than a stream?

```
using (var hasher = SHA1.Create())
    return hasher.ComputeHash(byteArray);
```

I've encountered some info suggesting that the managed version of some algorithms might be stateless, possibly allowing ComputeHash to be called multiple times on the same object, but that makes me wonder if that also means there is no real cost associated with creating a new object each time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both creating the hash function object and the hashing itself are relatively cheap. You can reuse an hash function object calling `ComputeHash` several times, but it's not threadsafe. I wouldn't bother with reuse unless your profiler indicated that it's expensive. The main issue is that you need to cache the response body so you can first hash it and then return it.

Comment: `SHA1.Create.ComputeHash(shortArray)` seems to cost around 10us, so you should consider reusing it once you reach around 10000 requests per second. If the data is short, `new SHA1Managed` will be much faster, but for long data the CSP wrapper wins. If it's two slow, consider using native interop to call OpenSSL. That should result in a factor 10 or so speedup, at least for short messages.

Comment: Legend thanks!  Good to know about CSP vs Managed - I can select based on the response content type.  AFAICT, ActionFilter seems to work pretty easily for pipelining in the hash etag.